# hammer.js: call event just once

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

So I'm making this fitness app and I'm fairly new to hammer.js. So I made this code:

```
var element = document.getElementById('swipe');
var trainings = new Array();
trainings = ["Cross Trainer", "Push ups", "Plank"];
var header = document.getElementById('title');

Hammer(element).on('panright', function(event){
    var training = trainings[0];

    if(header.innerHTML != training) {

        header.innerHTML = training;

        if (training == "Cross Trainer") {
            element.innerHTML = "10 min";
        } else if (training == "Push ups") {
            element.innerHTML = "2 x 10 Wiederholungen";
        } else if (training == "Plank") {
            element.innerHTML = "2 x 10 Wiederholungen";
        }

        trainings.shift();
        trainings.push(training);
    }
});
```

It's a test and I want to like swipe through exercises so I used panright. It works, but the function is called multiple times.

How do I prevent this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: That event may get fired a lot, try one that is likely to get fired only once. Like `panend` for example. http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-pan/